# Prevent default 'ctrl pageup' and 'ctrl pagedown' in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, cross-browser, keyboard-shortcuts

I have some code to create hotkeys for a web application. All of the hotkeys work in IE and Firefox, however <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>PgUp</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>PgDn</kbd> are not working in Chrome.

After digging around for answers and writing some custom test code, I believe I have determined that this is because those events fire, in Chrome, on keyup instead of keydown.

The default Chrome handlers for those events are firing instead of mine (or at least first) and switching the browser to the next or previous tab. If I use the hotkey to switch back to the tab with my application then my handlers catch the event.

So my question is, is there any way to catch these events in Chrome and prevent the default functionality from running?

The code in question is:

```
           //These work in IE and Firefox
            $(this).bind('keydown', 'ctrl+pageup', (evt) => {
                this.prevPage();
                return false;
            });

            $(this).bind('keydown', 'ctrl+pagedown', (evt) => {
                this.nextPage();
                return false;
            });

           //These catch the event in chrome, but it's too late
           $(this).bind('keyup', 'ctrl+pageup', (evt) => {
                this.prevPage();
                return false;
            });

            $(this).bind('keyup', 'ctrl+pagedown', (evt) => {
                this.nextPage();
                return false;
            });
```

It does exactly what I want in IE and Firefox, but not Chrome. I have tried `evt.preventDefault()`, `evt.stopImmediatePropagation` and `evt.stopPropagation`. However, it does not work (I believe because my handlers are being called after the browser handlers).

Comment: May be related: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=149751 (was marked as WontFix)

Comment: I've decided to give up on this for now.
The requirements were loose on what the key combination should be so I added support for ctrl+shift+pageup/pagedown for the chrome users.

If anyone does have an answer though I'd love to hear it!

Comment: Give us a fiddle to work with!

Answer (score 0):

Check a similar question on this link:

[Chrome - Javascript prevent default Ctrl + MouseWheel behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17864249/chrome-javascript-prevent-default-ctrl-mousewheel-behavior)

They say its impossible on chrome and its still being addressed!